# How to create a legend for bar colors in a Highcharts bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I use different colors for the bars in a Highcharts bar chart to denote two different groups of data like so (abbreviated):

```
$(function () {
    $('#moduleDistribution').highcharts({
        colors: ['red', 'red', '#1aadce', '#1aadce'],
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            showInLegend: false,
            data: [
                ['node', 291],
                ['wifi', 289],
                ['timer', 289],
                ['net', 285]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Luob5k8/4/

How can I create a legend (or similar) to explain the meaning of the colors? I'd like to explain to the viewer why some bars are red and some are not.

Comment: you can do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/7Luob5k8/7/ if you have only 2 colorsv

Comment: Good point, I could actually make two series with individual colors, thanks. Pls add it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using 2 series. Make them visible in the legend. Assign the color you want to  it. mention Category names in xAxis and use a [x,y] co-ordinates system to send the data to the chart.

your categories

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['node', 'wifi', 'timer', 'net', 'gpio', 'file', 'uart', 'i2c', 'mqtt', 'adc', '1wire', 'bit', 'pwm', 'spi', 'u8g', 'cjson', 'ws2812', 'coap']
},
```

your series will look like this.

```
        series: [{
            data: [
            [0, 291],
            [1, 289],
            [2, 289],
            [3, 285],
            [4, 284],
            [5, 283],
            [6, 263]
        ],
        color: '#FF0000'
    }, {

        data: [
            [7, 135],
            [8, 119],
            [9, 100],
            [10, 96],
            [11, 89],
            [12, 80],
            [13, 65],
            [14, 60],
            [15, 57],
            [16, 46],
            [17, 20]
        ],
        color: '#1aadce'
    }]
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Luob5k8/7/) I've updated your fiddle

Comment: The problem with that approach though is that I need to change the order of the x-axis categories whenever the order of the data series changes. I need the bars ordered (largest value left-most). Also, the idea fails if the bars with the same color are not adjacent to each other (e.g. 1st and 3rd bar red). Somewhere I saw a notation similar to this `['node', {y:291,color:'red'}]` for a data point but that doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Ok, the notation is `{name:'node', y:291, color: 'red'}`. This gives me all the flexibility I need for coloring the bars but of course I've still got no (meaningful) legend because there's just a single series: http://jsfiddle.net/7Luob5k8/8/.

Comment: I've been searching high and low how to create a custom legend from scratch but I really looks like Highcharts doesn't support that. Thanks for your help.